# How to get a class component type and add props to it's type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-video

I'm using [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video) together with [@mux/mux-data-react-native-video](https://github.com/muxinc/mux-stats-sdk-react-native-video).

Mux is used to wrap react-native-video's Video component to add data analytics features to it, so it's basically a wrapper that add extra props (e.g. `muxOptions`)

But mux's library don't have typescript support and I'm trying to type.

To use mux you basically do this:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import muxReactNativeVideo from 'mux-react-native-video-sdk';

// wrap the `Video` component with Mux functionality
const MuxVideo = muxReactNativeVideo(Video);
```

and then `MuxVideo` should have the same type as `Video` but with one extra prop that I'm going to create the types myself (`muxOptions`).

But the problem comes to how can I extend the props of the `Video` component

`Video`(react-native-video) component's type:

```
export default class Video extends React.Component<VideoProperties> {
    seek(time: number, tolerance?: number): void;
    presentFullscreenPlayer(): void;
    dismissFullscreenPlayer(): void;
}
```

What I want is to create a type that uses `typeof Video` but adds an interface that I will create (e.g. `MuxOptions`) to the props.

So the final result would be something like

```
//                                            the same type but with MuxOptions
export default class Video extends React.Component<VideoProperties & MuxOptions> {
    seek(time: number, tolerance?: number): void;
    presentFullscreenPlayer(): void;
    dismissFullscreenPlayer(): void;
}
```

I do understand that I could just copy paste the type of `Video` and add `MuxOptions` (just like the example above), but I don't want to do that because if the type of `Video` is changed in future versions of `react-native-video`, the types will break.

What I would like is just some generic type that merges an interface into the component props (and the hard part is that it's a class component).

Something like

```
interface MuxOptions { /* ... */ }

type MuxVideoType = MergeInterfaceIntoComponentProps<typeof Video, MuxOptions>

//    MuxVideo is the same as Video, but with MuxOptions on it's props
const MuxVideo: MuxVideoType = muxReactNativeVideo(Video)
```